# Звук отрицания письменно

Tags: частица, междометие

Есть ли способ письменной передачи звука (частицы? междометия?) отрицания? Он звучит как-то так: «у-у» (как «угу» без Г)/«мху-ху», взаимозаменяем с «неа». Надеюсь, ясно объяснил, что за звук подразумеваю.

Comment: @БотБотович спасибо, а почему написали в комментарий, а не в ответ?

Comment: Решил написать комментарий потому, что не настолько уверен в своём мнении. Если хотите, могу переделать в ответ.

Comment: Давайте, конечно. Плюс это мнение заслуживает

Comment: Зависит от предпочтения автора. Наиболее используемые междометия, как я считаю, уже зарегистрированы письменно, однако здесь же отмечу, что, например, для выражения удивления, восклицания и прочего используется целая группа слов: "ах", "ух" и тд. Так почему бы и не сделать собственные звуки и задать им значения? Тем более, как я понимаю, они достаточно распространены в разговорной речи.

Comment: @Aer♦ а что не так с этим ответом? Он почему-то снова стал комментарием

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, за что был удалён ответ. На мой взгляд, я сделал всё правильно, удалив комментарий и создав аналогичный ответ.